# Measuring incremental revenue without control group

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian

We recently installed a new incentive program for my company's top salespeople that would give them higher and higher revenue percentage cuts from sales. I'm trying to answer how much more incremental sales are due to only the new incentives program. We have given these incentives to only our highest salespeople, so there is already some bias comparing it to other sellers in the company. These incentivized sellers also have access to other resource in the company which other salespeople don't have. Would there be any way to due a comparison of these groups without a proper test vs control?